# How to change an estimote beacon's UUID through estimote android sdk?

Tags: android, beacon, estimote

Good afternoon. I'm developing an android app and I'm trying to integrate an estimote beacon with the app. The thing is I want be able to discover a specific device change the device's UUID, minor, major.

To discover and range the beacons I'm using:

```
    beaconManager.startRanging(region);

            beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> list) {

                    if (!list.isEmpty()) {

                        for(Beacon b : list){

                            if (b.getMacAddress().equals(macaddress)){

 %%Now that i have the Beacon b I would like to change it's UUID, major and minor.
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Can somebody help me? I know that in order to change the UUID I need to be connected to the estimote cloud but I'm not quite getting how (The example on their website uses BeaconConnection which is deprecated).

Comment: You cant change the UUID of iBeacon.

Comment: @AjayShrestha yes you can for estimote

Answer (score 1):

I use this method, I found on Estimote [andriod sdk](https://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/com/estimote/sdk/connection/BeaconConnection.html), it is deprecated by Estimote, but works with out problem by using the proper api setting in android studio.

I was not able to find alternative solution yet, but if I found I will update my answer.

```
private void editBeacon(final Beacon beacon, UUID newUuid, int newMinor, int newMajor) {
    connection = new BeaconConnection(this, beacon, new BeaconConnection.ConnectionCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthorized(BeaconInfo beaconInfo) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(BeaconInfo beaconInfo) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Authenticated to beacon. Info: " + beaconInfo);
            Log.d(TAG, "Advertising internal: " + connection.advertisingIntervalMillis().get());
            Log.d(TAG, "Broadcasting transmitPower: " + connection.broadcastingPower().get());
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError(EstimoteDeviceException exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Authentication Error: " + exception);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected");
        }
    });

    connection.authenticate();

    // Interact with beacon.

    // You can update beacon's properties in following way:
    connection.edit()
            .set(connection.proximityUuid(), newUuid)
            .set(connection.major(), newMajor)
            .set(connection.minor(), newMinor)
            .commit(new BeaconConnection.WriteCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(EstimoteDeviceException exception) {
                }
            });

    // Do not forget to close connection.
    connection.close();
}
```